# HERE Maps API: Unable to store the response

Tags: vba, excel, maps, response, here-api

I am using HERE Maps geocodding API with VBA to validate my address and give the lat & longs of the the address. I get the response but am unable to store and use the response.

Following is my code:

```
Private Sub Execute_Click()

    Dim address, address1, address2, address3, state, city, zip As String
    Dim appId As String
    Dim appCode As String
    Dim hereServerName As String
    Dim strQuery As String
    Dim strLatitude As String
    Dim strLongitude As String
    Dim addressGeocode As String
    Dim hereResult As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim hereService As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Dim rNodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim rNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

    hereServerName = "https://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.xml?"
    appId = "uL2kjU0xrylpwTQIgrl7"
    appCode = "2jhjonGD4MXzODki5T62Mg"

    Dim succ, actions As Integer
        succ = 0
        actions = 9
        For Row = 2 To actions
            On Error Resume Next
            address1 = Sheet1.Range("C" & Row)
            address2 = Sheet1.Range("D" & Row)
            address3 = Sheet1.Range("E" & Row)
            city = Sheet1.Range("F" & Row)
            state = Sheet1.Range("G" & Row)
            zip = Sheet1.Range("H" & Row)
            If address1 <> "" Then
                address = address1
            End If
            If address2 <> "" Then
                address = address & "," & address2
            End If
            If address3 <> "" Then
                address = address & "," & address3
            End If
            address = address & "," & city & "," & state & "," & zip
            address = URLEncode(address)
            strQuery = hereServerName & "searchtext=" & address & "&app_id=" & appId & "&app_code=" & appCode & "&gen=9"
            hereService.Open "GET", strQuery, False
            hereService.send
            hereService.waitForResponse
            'I get the repose for the request but i am unable to store it in the here Result[Xml response][1]
            MsgBox (hereService.responseText)
            hereResult.LoadXML (hereService.responseText) 'Result not being stored
            'I am unable to retrive any data from this statment.
            Set rNodes = hereResult.getElementsByTagName("DisplayPosition")
            For Each rNode In rNodes
                strLatitude = rNode.ChildNodes(0).ChildNodes(0).Text
                strLongitude = rNode.ChildNodes(0).ChildNodes(1).Text
                addressGeocode = strLatitude & "," & strLongitude
            Next rNode
            Sheet1.Range("I" & Row) = addressGeocode
        Next Row
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Public Function URLEncode(ByVal StringVal As String, Optional SpaceAsPlus As Boolean = False) As String

  Dim StringLen As Long: StringLen = Len(StringVal)
  If StringLen > 0 Then
    ReDim result(StringLen) As String
    Dim i As Long, CharCode As Integer
    Dim Char As String, Space As String
    If SpaceAsPlus Then Space = "+" Else Space = "%20"
    For i = 1 To StringLen
      Char = Mid$(StringVal, i, 1)
      CharCode = Asc(Char)
      Select Case CharCode
      Case 97 To 122, 65 To 90, 48 To 57, 45, 46, 95, 126
        result(i) = Char
      Case 32
        result(i) = Space
      Case 0 To 15
        result(i) = "%0" & Hex(CharCode)
      Case Else
        result(i) = "%" & Hex(CharCode)
      End Select
    Next i
    URLEncode = Join(result, "")
  End If
End Function
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: "unable to store and use the response" - you might need to expand on this a little.  It would help to include an example of what the response looks like.  If the response is JSON then you should look at https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to store it. I just stored the response in a temporary variable `strValue` and then used that

[image]

```
strValue = (hereService.responseText)
hereResult.LoadXML (strValue)
```

Since you are using a loop, please ensure that `hereService.responseText` is actually returning something for that element of the loop.

Also please avoid using OERN (`On Error Resume Next`). It is like telling the code to "Shut Up". Handle the errors in the right manner.

**Edit**

Here is part of a completely tested code

```
strValue = (hereService.responseText)
hereResult.LoadXML (strValue)

strLatitude = hereResult.getElementsByTagName("Latitude").Item(0).Text
strLongitude = hereResult.getElementsByTagName("Longitude").Item(0).Text
addressGeocode = strLatitude & "," & strLongitude

Sheet1.Range("I" & Row) = addressGeocode
```

**Screenshot**

Tested it on a Pizza Hut Location (**Damn I am hungry now :P**)

[image]